# How do I re-use JavaScript code in Spotfire?

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

How do I call other JavaScript in Spotfire. 
For example, JS written on Page 1 has to be called in Page 10.

Earlier I used to write the same function on both pages, I know how to call/reuse python script which written already, and in a similar manner, I would like to re-use JS Function.

Answer (score 1):

Is your JS on page 1 in a text area? If so, you can create a reusable script, just like IPython in Spotfire. To do this, edit the HTML where you want JS (you need to have a text area somewhere), then select insert JavaScript. You can create a new script here that can be called across the entire document.

[image]